# Is the correct date format April 1st, 2016?

Tags: dates, format

I have an aversion to this format, and I'd like to know the correct usage.

Comment: There's no singular correct date format, conventions vary by locality. If you want to know for a specific country/context then that could be answered but no country's format is more or less correct than the others.

Answer (score 1):

So many date options!

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Map for a world map vs preferred date-format.

The MDY in the question looks horrible to me, but I guess that is just because I am accustomed to DMY.

Answer (score -2):

Correct usage dictates one of the following:

April 1, 2016 or 1 April 2016

or

April 1st

When it comes to numerical date values, this can get trickier due to audience. In the US, we always list the month first in a numerical date (4/1 or 4/1/2016), but for most of the rest of the world, the day of the month comes first, followed by the month (1/4 or 1/4/2016).

ISO standards follow a different format: 2016-04-01.

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/how-to-formally-write-the-date.html

http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/writing-dates

Comment: I have never seen that ISO style in any actual text....

Comment: ...And in the UK, the most usual form is 1 April 2016 which follows D/M/Y use, and allows alternating text and figures when the day is put in front. To make such a dogmatic statement as your opening sentence risks being wrong -- or at least, not wholly correct.

Comment: ISO 8601 actually requires "2016-04-01" (the punctuation is optional).

Comment: @PaulRowe absolutely correct! I had too many things going on at work and was rewriting... will edit the post.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I actually included that in my original but deleted it because I couldn't find anything that supported my belief/recollection on that... Glad to know it wasn't just a mis-remembrance!

Comment: And to be fair to myself, the @OP did phrase the question in the US format. The question is about the use of the suffix to the day numeral, which is what I had originally written. But then it occurred to me that there may be questions about numeric format as well. Dates can be very confusing to decipher sometimes.

Comment: @Lambie, we do use it here at work on some documents... but not all, unfortunately!